# Mysql 1242 Error when executing a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is the body of my procedure is successfully created

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test.calculoSistema()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE FNacimiento TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    SET FNacimiento = (select DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL fnacimiento SECOND)     from participants);
    select FNacimiento from participants;
    END;
```

Running this procedure fails (MySQL ha dicho: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row), the solution to this would be using ANY query within the procedure, but mysql return an error # 1064, since then I've been standing with my work.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test.calculoSistema()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE FNacimiento TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    SET FNacimiento = ANY (select DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL fnacimiento SECOND)     from participants);
    select FNacimiento from participants;
    END;
```

What I want to do is pass the date to timestamp unix into a variable because the query is very large.

Your comments and responses will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the logic of the stored procedure, but the following should eliminate the `ERROR 1064`. I'm not sure if `ANY` solves the problem of the subquery:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`calculoSistema`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `FNacimiento` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    SET `FNacimiento` = ANY (SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL `fnacimiento` SECOND) FROM `participants`);
    SELECT `FNacimiento` FROM `participants`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```